# How to set beans loading order in annotation-based config with multiple profiles?

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I have the 'prod' and 'dev' profiles defined in my Spring-based application.

I have a service that defined to work with prod data. And I need a version for development to return some mocked data.

I've defined the dev service as follows:

```
@Profile('dev')
public DevService implements AService { ... }
```

And I have the prod service that defined as:

```
@Profile('prod')
public ProdService implements AService { ... }
```

For the development purpose, I'm just adding the 'dev' profile to existing ones, which also contain the 'prod' profile:

```
spring.profiles.active="prod","profile1","profile2","dev"
```

I know that to avoid conflicts I have to define the ProdService with not dev profile:

```
@Profile('!dev')
public ProdService implements AService { ... }
```

But I wanted to know is there a way to leave the 'prod' profile for the `ProdService`, and define an order or priority of loading the beans somehow using the annotation based approach?

Comment: Ordering won't help as all the beans will be loaded regardless of the ordering. Also why enable both `dev` and `prod` what do you gain if you enable all of them? You can mark one of the with `@Primary` so that that one will be used when multiple are on the class path.

Comment: @Primary: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html?

Comment: Thanks! That is what I exactly wanted to find!

Answer (score 1):

Although one can use annotations like `@Order`, `@DependsOn`, `@Primary`, `@Lazy` there is no explicit Spring bean order. It depends on the dependencies between singleton beans in the context. For example if bean `A` uses `@Autowried` constructor injection and depends on bean `B` than `B` has to be initialized first.

In your example you can use `@Primary`

```
@Profile('dev')
@Primary
public DevService implements AService { ... }
```

however if you are auto-wiring by type you can only have a single `@Primary` bean. Having more than one will get you back to square one and the bean won't be auto-wired.